# Passkey pattern for template class, problem with friend and template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, friend

This is the classical 'passkey' pattern which allows a function to be accessible only within the scope of a specific class:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class passkey {
private:
  friend T;
  passkey() {}

  // noncopyable
  passkey(const passkey&) = delete;
  passkey& operator=(const passkey&) = delete;
};

struct A {
    A();
};

void g(int i, passkey<A>) {
    std::cout << i;
}

A::A(){g(42,{});} 

int main() {

    A a;

    return 0;
}
```

Here the funtion `g` can only be called within `A`. But is it possible to extend it if `A` is now a template class? The following snippet does not compile (with clang, but it works with gcc...), because for a template friend, it seems that one must use an *elaborated-class-specifier*, which seems to lead to a declaration conflict...

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <template<typename...> class T>
class passkey {
private:
  template<typename...> friend class T;
  passkey() {}

  // noncopyable
  passkey(const passkey&) = delete;
  passkey& operator=(const passkey&) = delete;
};

template<typename T>
struct A {
    A();
};

void g(int i, passkey<A>) {
    std::cout << i;
}

template<typename T>
A<T>::A(){g(42,{});} 

int main() {

    A<void> a;

    return 0;
}
```

This gives with clang:

```
>source>:6:38: error: declaration of 'T' shadows template parameter
  template<typename...> friend class T;
                                     ^
<source>:3:39: note: template parameter is declared here
template <template<typename...> class T>
```

Is there any trick to have that work?

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that your variadic template actually compiles with GCC. This is how I would actually write it:

```
template <template<typename... Ts> class T, typename... Ts>
class passkey {
  private:
    friend class T<Ts...>;

    constexpr passkey() {
      return;
    }
    passkey(passkey const&) = delete;
    passkey& operator=(passkey const&) = delete;
};
```

Furthermore I would let the function `g` take an r-value reference and call it with `std::move` explicitly.

[Try it here!](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kax8HtSvAASdMKij)

Comment: But then, you only allow specific `A` as `A<void>`, but not `A<int>`, or you need to make `g` template too.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, sure, but isn't that what the OP is trying to do with his code?

Comment: I understand as "passkey for any `A`". Adding `Ts...` is mostly useless as you could directly use `template <typename T> void g(int i, passkey<A<T>>)` with first snippet.

Comment: @Jarod42 It is not clear what the OP wants to do with `Ts...`. If you don't use `Ts...` later on then yes clearly, no need to variadically template it but if you plan to use `Ts...` inside `passkey` then my approach is indeed useful. Furthermore I highly doubt that something like `template<typename...> friend class T;` which makes you then friend with any `T<...>` is actually legit C++. ICC and MVSC will complain about it as well.

Comment: Hardcoding `A` in `passkey` is accepted. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xdWsWWr8Y). As I understand, OP wants to to it generic.

Comment: @Jarod42 Of course but that is not the same. I intended to say that the second code snippet by the OP only compiles with GCC but not with Clang, ICC and MSVC and I doubt that it is a coincidence. If you are right and the OP wants it to be generic then indeed my answer is insufficient.

Comment: Yes, I would like this to be generic (not having to re-write the passkey class at each time...)

Comment: @janou195  I don't know if I am missing a point there but you don't need to rewrite the passkey class each time. @Jarod42's objection was that in my code `passkey<A,void>` can only be called by `A<void>` and not by e.g. `A<int>`. `A<int>` can only access its `passkey<A,int>` etc.. GCC in your second code example allows `A<void>` to access not only `passkey<A,void>` but also `passkey<A,int>` etc. but as said I don't think that this is allowed by the C++ standard: It fails to compile on all other standard compilers (MVSC, Clang, ICC).

Comment: @2b-t yes sorry, I reacted to the hardcoding of `A` in `passkey`. Wiht respect to your answer, I would like not to have to specify an actual class like `A<void>` or `A<int>`, but give access to any class created from the template class `A`

Comment: @janou195 No problem but I do not think that this is actually possible then.